# how to force email link to open in new window

Tags: javascript, html, outlook

The email link in an email is generated by a system using html, javascript, java. The email link should open from outlook in new window, not new tab. How do we do code in the email?

Comment: Tell the users to hold the shift key when they click the link.  That's probably the only way to make sure it will open in a new window for both IE and Firefox.

Comment: @austin Where did you learn that from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open url in new tab using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: @Ian It's just something that works on my versions of Firefox and IE to override the default behavior.  Holding Ctrl will force it to open in a new tab.

Comment: @austin Ahh yes, I don't know why I questioned that. I didn't know about holding shift, but I knew holding control did something

Answer (score 1):

Opening in a new window or a new tab depends on the email client/browser settings.  The best you can do is to make the `target="_blank"` and hope the receiving person has the right settings.

Comment: @Redtiger Did you read the first sentence? There's no way to choose/force whether it's opened in a new tab or window from JavaScript. It's determined by the browser's settings

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.open('example.com');` in the javascript.  However, you should be aware that different email clients react to this differently; some may respond to this by opening up a new tab anyhow, or my opening in the same tab — and be aware that Javascript is generally blocked in email clients anyhow.

Your alternative is to use `target='blank'` in the HTML, though this is still not guaranteed.